# I need to be able to display the 2 lines of text in 5 columns and each columns text need to be different, all based off 1 dropdown?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to be able to display the 2 lines of text in 5 columns and each columns text need to be different,

all based off 1 dropdown?

```html
<script>
//*********************************************
// Function that Shows an HTML element
//*********************************************
function showDiv(divID)
{
 var div = document.getElementById(divID);
 div.style.display = ""; //display div
}

//*********************************************
// Function that Hides an HTML element
//*********************************************
function hideDiv(divID)
{
 var div = document.getElementById(divID);
 div.style.display = "none"; // hide
}
//*****************************************************************************
// Function that Hides all the Div elements in the select menu Value
//*****************************************************************************
function hideAllDivs()
{
 //Loop through the seclect menu values and hide all
 var selectMenu = document.getElementById("selectMenu");
 for (var i=0; i<=selectMenu.options.length -1; i++)
 {
  hideDiv(selectMenu.options[i].value);
 }
}
//*********************************************
// Main function that calls others to toggle divs
//*********************************************
function toggle(showID)
{
 hideAllDivs(); // Hide all
 showDiv(showID); // Show the one we asked for

}
</script>

<html>

<body onload="hideAllDivs();">

 <select id="selectMenu" 
  onchange="toggle(this.options[this.options.selectedIndex].value)">
  <option value="formNumber"> Select Industry </option>
  <option value="formNumber1"> Industry1 </option>
  <option value="formNumber2"> Industry2  </option>
  <option value="formNumber3"> Industry3  </option>
  <option value="formNumber4"> Industry4  </option>

 </select>
</body>


When I try to duplicate this code it does not hide the divs?

 <div id="formNumber"></div>
 <div id="formNumber1">Visitors:200<br>leads:200</div> 
 <div id="formNumber2">Visitors:300<br>leads:300</div>
 <div id="formNumber3">Visitors:500<br>leads:500</div>
 <div id="formNumber4">Visitors:700<br>leads:700</div>
```

I am not sure how to do the following off one drop-down selector?

Comment: Don't forget, that ID must be unique. So if duplicated block of divs is the same with the same div ids it is not gonna work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget, that ID must be unique. So if duplicated block of divs is the same with the same div ids it is not gonna work. You can use data-id attribute instead.

Also it is very handy to use jQuery and than you don't need to iterate over divs to hide or show them, it allows to do that with one method:

`$(selector).hide()` or `$(seceltor).show()` wjere selector it is any of valid css selector. You can find them [here](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

**Ooohh! I got you! Look at that example, it makes what you need**. If you chose industry in select, it appears, if you chose it again it is going to hide. But because of script leans on `change` event, you must to chose another industry to hide previous.

```js
let selectMenu = document.querySelector('#selectMenu')
let industryColumns = document.querySelector('.industry-columns')
let industries = {
  1: {
    columns: {
      1: {
        visitors: 200,
        leads: 100
      },
      2: {
        visitors: 300,
        leads: 200
      },
      3: {
        visitors: 500,
        leads: 400
      },
      4: {
        visitors: 600,
        leads: 600
      },
    }
  },
  2: {
    columns: {
      1: {
        visitors: 500,
        leads: 100
      },
      2: {
        visitors: 300,
        leads: 600
      },
      3: {
        visitors: 500,
        leads: 4900
      },
      4: {
        visitors: 300,
        leads: 800
      },
    }
  },  
  3: {
    columns: {
      1: {
        visitors: 200,
        leads: 700
      },
      2: {
        visitors: 400,
        leads: 700
      },
      3: {
        visitors: 500,
        leads: 400
      },
      4: {
        visitors: 200,
        leads: 400
      },
    }
  },
  4: {
    columns: {
      1: {
        visitors: 200,
        leads: 100
      },
      2: {
        visitors: 300,
        leads: 200
      },
      3: {
        visitors: 500,
        leads: 400
      },
      4: {
        visitors: 600,
        leads: 600
      },
    }
  },
}

function createIndustriesOptions(industries) {
  Object.keys(industries).forEach(id => {
    let option = document.createElement('option')
    option.value = id
    option.textContent = `Industry ${id}`
    selectMenu.appendChild(option)
  })
}

function fillIndustryColumns(indId) {
  let industry = industries[indId]
  Object.keys(industry.columns).forEach(col => {
    let data = industry.columns[col]
    let column = industryColumns.querySelector(`[data-column="${col}"]`)
    
    Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
      column.querySelector(`.${key}`).textContent = data[key]
    })
  })
}

function clearIndustry() {
  let columns = [...industryColumns.querySelectorAll('[data-column]')];
  columns.forEach(column => {
    column.querySelector('.leads').textContent = ''
    column.querySelector('.visitors').textContent = ''
  }) 
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
  createIndustriesOptions(industries)
})

document.querySelector('#selectMenu').addEventListener('change', e => {
  let industryId = e.target.value;
  if(industryId) {
    industryColumns.classList.add('visible');    
    fillIndustryColumns(industryId)
  } else {
    industryColumns.classList.remove('visible');
    clearIndustry()
  }
});
```

```css
.select-menu {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.industry-columns {
  display: none;
}
.industry-columns.visible {
  display: block;
}
.industry-wrapper {
  display:inline-block;
  width: 120px;
  border: 1px dashed #666;
}
.industry>div {
  padding: 5px;
}
.industry>div:not(:last-child) {
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #666;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
<select id="selectMenu" class="select-menu">
  <option value=""> Select Industry </option>
</select>

<div class="industry-columns">
  <div class="industry-wrapper">
    <div class="industry" data-column="1">
      <div>Visitors:<span class="visitors"></span></div> 
      <div>Leads:<span class="leads"></span></div> 
    </div> 
  </div>
  <div class="industry-wrapper">
    <div class="industry" data-column="2">
      <div>Visitors:<span class="visitors"></span></div> 
      <div>Leads:<span class="leads"></span></div> 
    </div> 
  </div>
  <div class="industry-wrapper">
    <div class="industry" data-column="3">
      <div>Visitors:<span class="visitors"></span></div> 
      <div>Leads:<span class="leads"></span></div> 
    </div> 
  </div>
  <div class="industry-wrapper">
    <div class="industry" data-column="4">
      <div>Visitors:<span class="visitors"></span></div> 
      <div>Leads:<span class="leads"></span></div> 
    </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please view my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Thanks but I need it to work like this:

Dropdown /
-industry1 - (Selected active dropdown Item)

-industry2

-column 1 --------|--column 2-------------|---column 3 --------| -----column 4---| -----column 5----|
Visitors 100      |  Visitors 200         |  visitors 300      |   visitors 400  |    visitors 500  |
leads 100         |  Leads 200            |   leads  300       |   leads 400     |    visitors 600  |

Based on option 1 which was selected it displays 5 sets of data per that option if another option is selected the visitor's numbers will change.

The reason for this is because each industry will display different figures on the 5 columns but 5 sets of data in the columns need to change because off value added.

[image: How it will work]

Comment: Do you mean that each of option in select list should fill all of 5 columns with its own set of data??

Comment: @TimurGilauri correct that is what needs to happen.

Comment: Check my snippet above. I have changed it so I guess it is exactly what you want.

Comment: @TimurGilauri , thanks I really appreciate it! That is perfect :)

Comment: Please, mark my answer as solution) and if you need some more help, ask!